# Comparing same dates returns OrderedAscending

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

Given this function:

```
    func isLessThanDate(dateToCompare: NSDate) -> Bool {
        var isLess = false
        print(self)
        print(dateToCompare)
        if self.compare(dateToCompare) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending {
            isLess = true
        }
        return isLess
    }
```

I get OrderedAscending with the same date.
[image]

Comment: millisecond difference probably. How are you creating the dates?

Comment: they are update dates on objects, but i can't see the milisecond difference, how can i print miliseconds of a nsdate to certificate your statement?

Comment: `print(self.timeIntervalSince1970)` and `print(dateToCompare.timeIntervalSince1970)`

Comment: Yes they are different, 1455011990.0 and 1455011990.25.

Comment: So where is the problem now? The code works exactly as intended.

Comment: no problem, i didnt know about it cause the print(NSDate) didnt output the mils.

Comment: @Godfather https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCalendar/isDate:inSameDayAsDate:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to ignore the millisecond differences, you can use `floor` on the two dates, but without knowing the exact intent of your code, I'm not sure if that's really what you want. See the comments on this answer for an alternative using `NSCalendar` functions.

BTW, you can simplify your function if you directly return a boolean value instead of using the `isLess` variable:

```
func isLessThanDate(dateToCompare: NSDate) -> Bool {
  return self.compare(dateToCompare) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
}
```

Comment: Using `floor` on dates is not the most stable solution. The best would be to use `NSCalendar` functions to set milliseconds to zero.

Comment: @Sulthan: You might explain your reasoning. I personally think this is nonsense. Or do you think there is any calendar where the offset to UTC is not a whole number of seconds?

Comment: There is no particular reason to use `NSCalendar` to round off the fractional seconds of an `NSDate`.